# Erlang :: Example for orddict:map()

Tags: erlang

can somebody give me an example of how orddict:map() is used in Erlang?

Comment: Here's an example: http://erldocs.com/R15B/stdlib/orddict.html?i=24&search=orddict#update_counter/3

Answer (score 4):

orddict:map(F,D) applies the function F to all key/value of the orddict and return a new orddict containing key/newvalue

```
1> D = orddict:new().
[]
2> D1 = orddict:store(1,"test",D).
[{1,"test"}]
3> D2 = orddict:store(2,"test",D1).
[{1,"test"},{2,"test"}]
4> D3 = orddict:store(3,"test",D2). 
[{1,"test"},{2,"test"},{3,"test"}]
5> orddict:map(fun(K,V) -> V ++ " " ++ integer_to_list(K) end, D3). 
[{1,"test 1"},{2,"test 2"},{3,"test 3"}]
6>
```